# How to fix skipping/stuttering audio in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, flash

If I play Google Music, or a Youtube video in the Chrome browser, and then open a new tab and start typing the address bar, the audio will quickly cut in and out as I am typing (with almost every letter I type).

It also is choppy if I play the video and start typing in the start menu. I can not repeat this behavior using internet explorer. Based on that Im thinking that it maybe a problem with the version of flash Chrome is using but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

I'm running 32-bit Windows 7, IE 9, and Chrome 23.0. PC is a Lenovo T43P. I have the latest sound drivers.

- IE is using Flash 11.5.502
- Chrome is using Flash 11.5.31.2

Only one (this) plugin is listed for Flash in the Chrome plugins list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by disabling the "pepper" Flash player and installing the latest full version of Flash.

To do this, go to `chrome://plugins/`  in the Chrome browser and disable the Flash plugin that's there (the location will be something like `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\23.0.1271.64\PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll`).

Once it's disabled you can go to `youtube.com` (or some other Flash-dependent website) and follow the hyperlinks provided to get the latest version of Flash (or just go directly to the Adobe Flash website and get it there).

Comment: I have noticed the same issue. I am using Google Chrome 23.0.1271.64m on Windows XP, the included flash plugin is 11.5.31.2 and causes garbled sound. My solution was disable the included plugin and manually install the latest version of flash player, 11.5.502.110 at this time.

Comment: I have the same issue as well.  Switching to the non pepper flash player fixes the stuttering, but causes the audio quality to be reduced.  Closer to radio instead of CD quality.  Perhaps it's bypassing the treble and bass settings I have set in control panel?

Comment: I don't think this will work anymore because Chrome is disabling all plugins?