# How to fix audio/game stuttering in Google Chrome's Flash plug-in?

Tags: google-chrome, performance, audio, flash, gaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix skipping/stuttering audio in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/503692/how-to-fix-skipping-stuttering-audio-in-google-chrome)

I'm having an issue. Windows XP, running the latest Chrome 23 build. I'm using Flash 11.5 built into Chrome (Pepper Flash). It runs horribly. Chrome 22 did not have this issue as far as I recall. What a shame.

YouTube videos stutter badly and after a while, they begin to lag and lose sync with the video. I disabled Pepper Flash and tested HTML5 video in YouTube and it was smooth as glass. Additionally, certain Flash based games are almost unusable now. The plug-in is using 100% CPU and it lags horribly in these games. Google/Adobe, please fix this. I shouldn't have to disable the built-in Flash plug-in (with added sandboxing security) and use regular Flash to resolve this. Short of waiting for an update to Chrome, does anyone have a better solution to fixing this? I am all ears.

Answer (score 0):

Go to chrome://plugins in your browser.

You'll most likely see flash player in the list as an expandable item - here, you can disable the shipped-with-chrome version and instead use the system version (which you install from adobe direct).

It certainly fixed my flash woes.