# How to resolve the speed and video streaming issue in google chrome

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, speed, youtube

I have got latest chrome installed in windows platform. The youtube videos are not coming properly, There is voice distortion and the pages are loading bit slow. scrolling is not smooth and It will take some time to display the search results also.

When i opened the Task manager, there were many "chrome.exe" processes (had opened one tab)

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: Does this only happen in Chrome, does the issue exist in IE/Firefox as well?

Comment: Try enabling/disabling hardware acceleration and see if it makes a difference. Also try [normal Flash instead of the in-built one](http://superuser.com/a/503695/138343).

Comment: @Dave Rook It happens only in chrome.

Comment: @Karan, The video streaming issue has been resolved after nanually installing the flash player, But the scrolling issue is there, Scrolling is not smooth and it gives me overlapping feeling

Comment: @Vinay go at the end of the page and press home button .. is it smooth moves or not ???

Comment: Did you try enabling/disabling h/w acceleration in [Chrome](http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2011/03/03/speed-up-google-chrome-by-enabling-hardware-acceleration-and-pre/) or [YouTube](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1230977)? You can also try fiddling with the [smooth scrolling setting](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-smooth-scrolling-feature-in-google-chrome/)

Comment: @Karan yes, I have tried the mentioned solutions But still the problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely scenario is your operating system running out of resources, and/or memory leak in Chrome.

Try to restart Chrome. If you wish to restore your current browsing session, click on the **Chrome options icon on the top-right (the last button after the address/omnibar) -> Settings -> On startup -> Continue where I left off**. Then, click on the Chrome options icon again, and **Exit**. When you relaunch Chrome again, your session will be restored and stale system resources freed.

Another likely performance problem is the [Youtube HTML5 trial](http://www.youtube.com/html5). If you see `You are currently in the HTML5 trial.`, click on `Leave the HTML5 Trial`.