# How do I fix skipping and stuttering sound in Google Chrome on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, windows-8.1, audio

When I try to play Pandora, it skips and stutters. I have 8 cores and 32GB, no reason to stutter. I tried the steps in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/503692/how-to-fix-skipping-stuttering-audio-in-google-chrome#503695), installed Flash player [directly from Adobe](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) and restarted the browser, but only `pepflashplayer.dll` showed up in `chrome://plugins/`

Pandora requires Flash to operate. I have "Use hardware acceleration when available" turned on.

Chrome Version 54.0.2840.87 m, Version 54.0.2840.99 m

Comment: `--audio-buffer-size=512` does not help either.

Comment: 8 cores and 32GB of RAM doesn't mean that it'll play any videos smoothly. Although it's unlikely on any modern PCs, but for example an ancient server with 8 Pentium 3 cores might not be able to run 4K videos properly.

Comment: This looks like DPC issues. Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk which also works in Win8), run WPRUI.exe, load and check this profile inside WPRUI.exe (Add Profiles) https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rl4r784kvnhypf/Multimedia_WPRP.WPRP?dl=1 and click on **Start**. Now capture 1 minute of the audio issues. After 1 minute click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file (+ NGENPDB fodler) into 1 zip, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here. I'll try to analyze it

Comment: have you captured the trace?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here is file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9XPKIrgZLLuNm1XWHpRZEpuQ1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ok, you have no DPC or ISR issue.highest DPC delay is between 256 and 512µs in ndis.sys (network related drive, no wonder if you do network IO and listen music). your realtek NIC driver is old (Rt630x64.sys", "8.020.0815.2013"), so try the latest 8.049: http://12244.wpc.azureedge.net/8012244/drivers/rtdrivers/cn/nic/0024-Install_Win8_8.1_8049_11212016.zip. I also see your WD disk is very busy. For your system you should use a SSD like the Samsung 850 EVO. Chrome may buffer file to disk and now the disk is busy reading the cache.

Comment: I clicked on 'Update Driver' in Control Panel and let it search for the best driver. It said 'The best driver software for your computer is already installed. Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date.'